# How to test SensorEventListeners with Robolectric?

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

Suppose I have something like

```
public class FizzBuzz implements SensorEventListener {

    String fizzBuzz;

    public int onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (SensorEvent.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) 
            return; 
        // if heading mod 360 < 180.0
            fizzBuzz = "fizz";
        // else
            fizzBuzz = "buzz";
    }

    public String getFizzBuzz() { /*... */ }

}
```

Suppose I want to test its behaviour and make sure that it actually sets the attribute to "fizz" when the device is headed somewhere between 0 and 180 degrees and "buzz" otherwise.

What is the proper way of doing this with Robolectric - that is, feeding fake `SensorEvents` and verifying that the output is the one I expected?

Comment: As for me it is proper way. You're not testing that android is calling my listener with events but you're testing that you listener correctly acts when even comes

Comment: @EugenMartynov thanks. What's, in practice, the difference in the latter approach, though?

Comment: Do you mean - "how can I trigger event from robolectric seamless to android"?